# Python FuelSDK for Python 2.7 version

Tags: fuel-sdk, python

I looked at the pypi documentation and it looks like SalesForce-FuelSDK for python supports Python 3.3 version. https://pypi.org/project/Salesforce-FuelSDK/

Has anyone figured out a way to get it working for Python 2.7 ?

I need a sdk that works for 2.7.

Thanks,
sahil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout this tag https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-Python/tree/v0.9.4. Its a stable version before python 3 support was added

Comment: Thanks  !! We ended up forking repo and making the appropriate changes to avoid the transitive dependencies conflict.